# Unity Profiling - Mesh.Bake PhysX CollisionData Doubling CPU cycles

Tags: unity, performance, profiling, physx

I have a mob that, when it dies, spawns smaller versions of itself.  When this happens there's a huge resource spike.  The profiler narrowed it down to baking the meshes of the new objects.  I have a couple of smaller questions related to this, but the crux of the issue is that it looks like the baking is occurring twice (doubling CPU usage) as shown below in both Instantiate and Transform.SetParent.  I'd normally say it's redundant, but in every way it looks like it's happening twice and take over one full second total.  Why would this happen twice on the same set of object (there are a variable number of spawned mobs, so the actual numbers can vary)?

As an aside, can this be backed in the prefab somehow to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

Currently, I've set the `isConvex` bool to `false`, which has resolved the immediate situation.  I'm not sure if this will impact anything else - with `RigidBody` attached to each mob, it doesn't appear to cause issues with collision, and so far it doesn't seem to cause any major issues with the mesh during animations, but this will need to be evaluated further.